# Почему возвращается None, а не список

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def price_num(x, num_list=[]):
    if x == 1:
        return num_list
    else:
        for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            num_list.append(x)
        price_num(x-1, num_list)

print(price_num(10))
```

Если выводить список *num_list* в самой функции, то выводится нужный список.

Comment: `return price_num(x-1, num_list)`

Comment: я не знаю как в питоне, но в яве чтобы метод что-то возвращал он должен быть не void

Comment: @ДмитрийАлексеенко В питоне типизация - это украшательство сверху, она не влияет на выполнение кода )  В этом коде нигде типы не описаны, не только у возврата функции

Comment: Заметьте только очень важную вещь, если Вы вызовете функцию второй раз, в виде `price_num(1)`, то она вернет Вам вовсе не пустой список, а список c результататом предыдущего вызова. Если такое поведение не предполагалось, подумайте что изменить.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что ваша функция ничего не возвращает по итогу. Что происходит: сначала в список добавляются рекурсивно числа 7, 5, 3, 2. Как только дело доходит до единицы, то вы возвращаете список, но этот возврат происходит в `price_num(2, num_list)`, а дальше вы выходите из рекурсии без всяких возвратов, поэтому правильно будет писать так:

```
def price_num(x, num_list=[]):
    if x == 1:
        return num_list
    else:
        for i in range(2, x // 2 + 1):
            if x % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            num_list.append(x)
        return price_num(x-1, num_list)

print(price_num(10))
```

*Небольшое замечание:* правильнее функцию назвать `prime_num`.